# Work with text output in a browser (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I have two texts on one line, how can I make it so that they are on different lines.

[image]

My Code

```
button.addClickListener(event -> {

    DomainDTO dto = domainDTO(URL(textField.getValue()));

    String txt = "";

    txt += "Domain Name............: " + dto.getDomainIfo().getDomainName();
    txt +=  "Organization Using Domain Name";



    text1.setText(txt);

        }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding newlines (`\n` for example) to your code will not make a newline in the browser.

You have a few options, either a more HTML route (**caution:** to avoid XSS, don't use this if you're not sure about the text contents).

```
text1.getElement().setProperty("innerHTML", "Row one<br>Row two");
```

Or you could use an element such as `Paragraph` that displays on its own line by default:

```
Paragraph row1 = new Paragraph("Row one");
Paragraph row2 = new Paragraph("Row two");

text1.add(row1, row2);
```

Comment: I strongly discourage the `innerHTML` approach since it can lead to XSS vulnerabilities if any of the strings are provided by the user (e.g. `dto.getDomainIfo().getDomainName()`). Also `Paragraph` gives a nicer API in this case since you can pass the text value to its constructor.

Comment: Ah, yes, `Paragraph` did not come to mind this early in the morning.

Comment: Hello can you open chat. I want to ask for advice

Answer (score 1):

@Tazavoo's answer is correct (the `Paragraph` approach) but I wanted to expand on that answer a little.

Based on the question, I believe OP is not aware of Vaadins basic HTML-Components like `Paragraph`, `Span`, `Div`, `VerticalLayout`, `HorizontalLayout`. I encourage the author of the question (and any reader new to Vaadin) to look through all of [Vaadins components](https://vaadin.com/components), and use those.

There is a [Layouting Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/tutorials/vertical-and-horizontal-layouts) which I also recommend going through.

[This Layouting overview](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-overview.html) Is written for Vaadin 8 (some Components like `Panel` are V8-specific), but it gives a great overview how to achieve a complex Layout by nesting `VerticalLayout` and `HorizontalLayout`, and using multiple `Label` components.

TL;DR
Do **NOT** write newlines or br-tags in strings that you append to the page. Whenever you write HTML code on the java side, you're on the wrong track. Use Vaadin Components and Layouts.